# Add Hardcoded row to AngularJS tableoptions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to angular and I have a page that will be using `dtable`. The table will be built in my controller but for the time being I want to add some hardcode rows until I am ready to populate my table with valid details but I have no idea how to do this.

**HTML**

```
<dtable class="full-height material" 
        style="height: 555px" 
        options="vm.tableoptions" 
        rows="vm.adviseraccess">
</dtable>
```

**Controller**

```
    var vm = this;
    vm.tableoptions =
    {
        rowHeight: 50,
        headerHeight: 30,
        footerHeight: 50,
        columnMode: 'force',
        columns:
        [
            {
                name: "Adviser Name",
                width: 75
            },
            {
                name: "Allow Access",
                width: 25
            }
        ],
    };
```

I tried seeing if adding `items` to my `tableoptions` would work as shown below but it doesn't

```
    vm.tableoptions =
    {
        rowHeight: 50,
        headerHeight: 30,
        footerHeight: 50,
        columnMode: 'force',
        columns:
        [
            {
                name: "Adviser Name",

                width: 75
            },
            {
                name: "Allow Access",

                width: 25
            }
        ],
        items:
        [
            {
                "name": "One"
            }
            {
                "name": "Two"
            }
        ]
    };
```

And I also tried the following

```
    vm.adviseraccess = [
        {
            name: "Antony"
        },
        {
            name: "Bob"
        },
        {
            name: "Will"
        }
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like This

```
<div ng-controller="AngularWayCtrl as showCase">
    <table datatable="ng" class="row-border hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in showCase.persons">
            <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.lastName }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

Controller

angular.module('showcase.angularWay', ['datatables', 'ngResource'])
.controller('AngularWayCtrl', AngularWayCtrl);

function AngularWayCtrl($resource) {
var vm = this;
vm.persons=[{
    "id": 860,
    "firstName": "Superman",
    "lastName": "Yoda"
}, {
    "id": 870,
    "firstName": "Foo",
    "lastName": "Whateveryournameis"
}, {
    "id": 590,
    "firstName": "Toto",
    "lastName": "Titi"
}, {
    "id": 803,
    "firstName": "Luke",
    "lastName": "Kyle"
}];
}
```

for more Details please Refer this Link [Angular-dataTables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay)